# Use of a trivial constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

> 12.1/5 A constructor is trivial if it is an implicitly-declared default constructor and if:
>
> —  its class has no virtual functions (10.3) and no virtual base
>   classes (10.1), and
>   —  all the direct base classes of its class have
>   trivial constructors, and
>    —  for all the nonstatic data members of its
>   class that are of class type (or array thereof), each such class has a
>   trivial constructor.

First I thought a trivial constructor is just an implicit default constructor. But when reading the above text in standard, it seems trivial constructor is not only a implicit default constructor but it has other requirements as mentioned above. What does it mean? Whats the point of having a trivial constructor?

For example:

```
class X
{
  // ...
};
```

Does class X has a trivial or implicit default constructor?

Answer (score 2):

It depends what's in the `// ...`.

Every trivial constructor is an implicitly-declared default constructor, but not every implicitly-declared default constructor is a trivial constructor. Class X has a trivial destructor if *it* has an implicit default, **and** every one of its base-classes has an implicit default (as well as those base-classes' base-classes, and so on), **and** every one of its members is either a primitive like `int` or else is of a type with an implicit default (as well as its members' members, and so on, as well as its members' base-classes, and their base-classes, and so on, as well its base-classes' members, and their members, and so on, and so on, and so on).

It may be easier to look at it the opposite way: if a class *doesn't* have a trivial constructor, then no class that extends it ("is-a") or includes it ("has-a") has a trivial constructor, either.

Answer (score 1):

Trivial constructor does nothing at all. The list from your post says that a constructor is trivial when:

1. You did not make your constructor do work by providing a non-default constructor
2. The bases of your class did not make your constructor do work associated with preparing to handle virtual functions, virtual base classes, or non-trivial constructors of their own
3. The data members of your class did not make your constructor do work associated with calling their own non-trivial constructors

These rules taken together mean that the constructor has nothing to do, hence it is *trivial*.

In case of `X`, it all depends on its data members: if they all have trivial constructors, and if you did not provide a non-trivial constructor yourself, `X` will have a trivial constructor too.

Comment: Can you explain how does the constructor do work associated with preparing to handle virtual functions?

Comment: @user1086635 Compiler adds a hidden pointer to the layout of classes with virtual functions, pointing to virtual function table (also called vtable). This pointer needs to be set before the class is ready for use.

Comment: But vtable is created at compile-time and when an object is created, a hidden pointer is set to vtable. In this process, constructor is never called at runtime then how it is used?

Comment: @user1086635 Of course it is: in this case, the code that sets the hidden pointer to the vtable is the non-trivial constructor.